# SPRING java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration after Add Quartz Schedule

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I get this error when debug project. I read
[Spring java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034329/spring-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-expression-spel-spelpars)
But It can't help me solved problem. 
Everything is ok util add 3 file below.
Full trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration.<init>(Lorg/springframework/expression/spel/SpelCompilerMode;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.<init>(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586) [catalina.jar:8.0.26.B]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750) [catalina.jar:8.0.26.B]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
00:00:48.893 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Mar 27 00:00:48 ICT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:415) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579) [spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115) [spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4774) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5390) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586) [catalina.jar:8.0.26.B]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750) [catalina.jar:8.0.26.B]
```

I created 3 file (MyJobOne, MyJobOne, QuartzConfiguration.java ) at http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-quartz-2-scheduler-integration-annotation-example-using-javaconfig#jobdetail

My pom.xml

```
    <!-- Quartz API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mapping -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- postgres -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- logback -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- log4jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.log4jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to declare an explicit dependency on the `spring-expression` library as well, *e.g.* by including the following in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I was add into pom. This time new trace log: <code>

Comment: Thanks. I was add into pom. This time new trace log:                                           
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyUtils.isScopedTarget(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Mar 27 11:34:46 ICT 2016]; root of context hierarchy

Comment: For that, looks like you'll need a similar `<dependency>` entry in your `pom.xml` for artifactId `spring-aop` (groupId `org.springframework`, version `4.2.5.RELEASE`).